# Unhandled exception in a thread spawned by a third-party dll - .net

Tags: c#, .net, exception, unhandled-exception

This is a follow up on:
[Unhandled DivideByZero exception from an external DLL - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087947/unhandled-dividebyzero-exception-from-an-external-dll-c-sharp)

I have a .net 4.0 application referencing a 3rd-party dll. One of the methods exposed by this dll internally spawns a thread, that at times throws a DivideByZero exception. Because the thread throwing the exception is different than the one calling the method, I cannot use try-catch to block the exception from propagating and crashing the program.

I used a handler to the following event, but while it does get called and allows
logging, it doesn't really "catch" the exception, which continues to propagate up.

```
 AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
 currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
```

Any idea what can be done to block the exception from crashing the program?

Comment: What type of application is it?

Comment: It's an executable (console application) that does file transfer. The dll is a 3-rd party FTP library.

Comment: if it's doing file transfer's and the error is `DivideByZero` exception.. I don't see how the 2 are related.. is there any other code or process that does divisional calculations which would indicate that something is trying to divide a number / 0

Comment: There is nothing on our sides that indicates a potential problem. This is why I am first trying to see how to catch this.

Comment: There is not any way in which you can catch the exception.  You'll need to run this code in another process so it cannot terminate yours.  A telephone is the better solution.